# How to add a colorbar to pandas.plotting.parallel_coordinates?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I try to create a parallel_coordinates plot where the line color indicates the value of a signal. The output of the plot is fine:

[image: sample plot]

But I would like to add a colorbar legend to this plot to explain the meaning of the colors.

```
thePlot: plt.Axes = parallel_coordinates(myDataFrame, class_column=class_column, cols=plotColumns, colormap='hot')
plt.colorbar(thePlot)
```

Crashes with `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_array'`, and

```
thePlot: plt.Axes = parallel_coordinates(myDataFrame, class_column=class_column, cols=plotColumns, colormap='hot')
plt.colorbar()
```

crashes with: `RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf).`

How to add a colorbar as legend?

Comment: The variable is "thePlot" - isn't it? or does it have to be "ax"?

Comment: Well, I program 70% of my time in JAVA ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parallel_coordinates` creates lots of individual short lines, each with its own color. Therefore, there is no element with information to create a colorbar.

You can create a colorbar from scratch with the same parameters:

```py
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(norm=plt.Normalize(df['coloring'].min(), df['coloring'].max()), cmap='hot'), ax=thePlot)
```